# Evaluating a Real Integral using Contour Integration

Tags: complex-analysis

I need to calculate $$\int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\ dx$$ by considering  $\oint_Cf(z)dz$ where $f(z)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{z^2-1}}$. To do so, we can use Cauchy's theorem to equate the integral around two different contours since the integrand $f(z)$ is analytic everywhere but the branch cut between -1 and 1. Using a circular contour with radius tending to infinity we get $\oint_Cf(z)dz=2\pi i$ (residue theorem) and collapsing the contour onto a path that just about encloses the branch cut we can relate this to the required integral - this is where my problem is. I'll start by writing down what the answer is:
$$\oint_Cf(z)dz=\int^{-1}_1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{e^{i\pi}(1-x)(1+x)}}\ dx+\int^1_{-1} \frac{1}{{\sqrt{e^{-i\pi}(1-x)(1+x)}}}\ dx$$ which comes out as $2i$ multiplied by the required integral, so clearly the required integral is $\pi$. Now I know that the phase factors are very important when going around the branch cut, but I struggle to see where they have come from here. When going from 1 to -1 we are ever so slightly above the cut, and then $z=xe^{i0}$ when $x>0$ and $z=|x|e^{i\pi}$ when $x<0$. When going from -1 to 1 we are ever so slightly below the cut, and then $z=|x|e^{i\pi}$ when $x<0$ and $z=xe^{i2\pi}$ when $x>0$. I can't really get any further than that. Thanks for any responses :)

Comment: The integral is not so real as stated in the title. What is the real value of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2-1}}$ in the midpoint $x=0$ of the integration range?

Comment: Sorry I wrote the denominator the wrong way!

Comment: It is much easier to just using trigonometric substitution... Contour integral is useful for improper integrals, but this is not the case.

Comment: Not really a good answer in an exam though eh ;)